# Political catchwords used to misguide?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, politics

I remember reading a Wikipedia article about a linguistic category of catchwords  used in politics which refer to ill-defined ideas. They are left purposefully vague so their exact meaning is left unanswered but sound nice and are used to attract rapport.

I've forgotten the term and would like to find it again.

Some examples might include things like;
"free speech", "respect", "civil rights", "fairness"

For example, regarding a bill which raises taxes for the rich, a politician might say "This bill is in the interests of fairness" knowing that;

1. The word itself will attract support- It sounds nice to support "fairness" and reflects poorly if you speak out against it (people might think that you are against "fairness")
2. Avoids going into the specifics of whether or not it is actually "fair" to raise taxes by using a term that has complex connotations that may change depending on the person who hears it- Is the degree it's being raised by fair? Is it actually fair to take from the rich and give to the poor? What is "fairness" exactly (is it zero sum? equality? equity? etc.)?

Edit: "fairness" definately wasn't one of the terms specified in the article but I think my example conveys the idea nonetheless.
---Think of buzzwords, soundbites etc.

Comment: The term isn't doublespeak, per se.  I do remember the article mentioning that the words are used with the express purpose of gaining support, as in their use in describing a position is statistically relevant in terms of political support.

Comment: When a question asks for help remembering something you have forgotten, it is subjective – a request for guesses or ideas, with the key criterion for answer correctness hidden in the mind of the asker. Unfortunately this is not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective enough to have a clearly “right” answer no matter who is asking. Otherwise, the answer is not useful to future visitors, and we are guessing when we answer or cast votes.

Comment: See: “[Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)”, and “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”. A welcoming place to ask for help remembering a word you have forgotten is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are thinking of ***doublespeak***, a term coined by George Orwell in his novel *Nineteen Eighty-Four*.  It refers to:

> ... language that deliberately obscures, disguises, distorts, or reverses the meaning of words. Doublespeak may take the form of euphemisms (e.g. "downsizing" for layoffs, "servicing the target" for bombing), in which case it is primarily meant to make the truth sound more palatable.
>
> It may also refer to intentional ambiguity in language or to actual inversions of meaning. In such cases, doublespeak disguises the nature of the truth. Doublespeak is most closely associated with political language.

(From the [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doublespeak))

The Oxford Living Dictionaries defines it as:

> ***[doublespeak](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doublespeak)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> *[mass noun]*
>
> Deliberately euphemistic, ambiguous, or obscure language.
>
> *‘the art of political doublespeak’*

Comment: This isn't the term I was looking for, though I am familiar with 1984. To further clarify, my idea of doublespeak was contradictory language used with the express purpose of reinforcing ideology. This is different from my understanding of "catchwords" that are used to conform with popular opinion by abusing the vagueness of social mores.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of the [soundbite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/soundbite) (also written sound bite)? It's something like a platitude which everyone can agree with; it's often left vague and in politics can gloss over the fact that nothing about specific policy has been mentioned.

From dictionary reference.

> Idioms and Phrases with sound bite
>
> A short, striking, quotable statement well suited to a television news
>   program. For example, He's extremely good at sound bites, but a really
>   substantive speech is beyond him. This slangy expression, first
>   recorded in 1980, originated in political campaigns in which
>   candidates tried to get across a particular message or get publicity
>   by having it picked up in newscasts.

Comment: Yes it shares the meaning of a soundbite or cliche but I'm looking for a more formal term. I think the article was perhaps the PoliSci term for the phenomenon as a whole. It was also referring to specific words/terms as opposed to quotable statements/sentences.

Comment: Does it have to be political? Another not necessarily political word is 'buzzwords'

Comment: It may perhaps be less political language and more jargon specific to the social sciences. The word (from my perspective) resembled a word with its roots in academia.

Comment: It might help if you knew what social scientists used it, e.g. more modern social scientists or more from 19th century.

Comment: One more try. It's not [concision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concision_(media_studies)) (as used in media studies) by any chance?

Comment: Nope. It also seems like concision is used as a tool to oppress as opposed to one that is used to appeal (?). I couldn't tell you who used it, it isn't a common term and I more or less stumbled upon the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Well it seems to encourage soundbites: "the beauty of that is you can only repeat conventional thoughts". In any case I assume you will know your word when you see it, and that this is not it.

Answer (score 0):

> [**platitude**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/platitude) *(noun)*
>
> **A remark or statement, especially one with a moral content, that has been used too often to be interesting or thoughtful.**
>
> *She began uttering liberal platitudes.*
>
> *It's pretty much downhill from there, with everyone speaking in moral platitudes and Hanks looking troubled.*
>
> *But members of the Omagh victims' group are not content with such platitudes.*

A **platitude** is very probably *ill-defined* and would likely *sound nice,* as per your question. (I had always assumed *platitude* was related to *please* but [apparently](https://www.etymonline.com/word/platitude) the original meaning was *flatness*.) Depending on the political context and the audience, *free speech, respect, civil rights* and *fairness* could all be reasonable components of a *platitude.*

Recognising something as a *platitude* is necessarily acknowledging a failing in it, so the word is used negatively (except perhaps by cynical political speechwriters).

*Platitudes* are likely to be woolly, saccharine, inoffensive and, upon the slightest examination, devoid of any real content and inane. The general and fuzzy nature of a *platitude* itself would not admit any concrete proposal, but something with actual substance - a different message or a policy announcement, perhaps - could be disguised by them; the commonly-used phrase here is **couched in platitudes**:

> ["Nazis vandalize campaign sign at home of gay Ohio congressional candidate. His response is amazing."](https://www.dailykos.com/stories/2018/7/6/1778589/-Nazis-vandalize-campaign-sign-at-home-of-gay-Ohio-congressional-candidate-His-response-is-amazing) *Daily Kos,* 6 July 2018
>
> *Hate has always run America. It’s just that over the last 30 or so years, the bigotry has been the more subtle and insidious kind, inspiring discriminatory policy **couched in platitudes** about opportunity and freedom.*

Words with meanings related to *platitude* include:<sup>[1](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/)</sup>

- **banal** (adjective) *boring because it contains nothing new, original, or unusual*
- **truism** (noun) *a statement that does not really need to be made because everyone already knows it is true*
- **cliché** (noun) *a phrase or idea that is boring because people use it a lot and it is no longer original*

---

Not a single word but **dog whistles** or **dog-whistle politics** refers to phrases loaded with inferences or coded meanings that only particular groups - the real target audience - will pick up on. To others, these coded messages may just sound like *platitudes.* (The *Daily Kos* quote above illustrating *couched in platitudes* shows the kind of context where the two terms, *dog whistles* and *platitudes,* might intersect.)

> [**dog
>   whistle**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/dog_whistle)
>   *(noun) [usually as modifier]*
>
> **A subtly aimed political message which is intended for, and can only be understood by, a particular group.**
>
> *dog-whistle issues such as immigration and crime*
>
> *What was striking about her reasons for voting Conservative was that, without any prompting, she chose two of Mr Howard's "dog whistle"
>   issues.*
>
> *Thatcher's was true dog-whistle politics, a subtle signal rather than the main message.*
>
> *He was party chairman at the 2005 general election when Michael Howard championed so-called "dog whistle" issues such as immigration
>   and Europe.*
>
> *In Howard's case it's a dog whistle message to blue collar Labour supporters.*
>
> *Equality of opportunity is the leftwing equivalent of a dog-whistle issue.*

The examples above are from a UK corpus and, as such, relate to British politics. The phrase is not as new as I, for one, would have thought; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog-whistle_politics#Origin_and_meaning) suggests that the term first arose in opinion polling in the late 1980s, where subtle differences in questions were observed to have a marked effect on results. *Dog whistles* then jumped from pollsters to campaign workers, perhaps changing usage in the process from an observed effect to a deliberate tactic.

The same article says the term gained prominence in Australia in the mid-90s in reference to John Howard's campaigning, and *dog whistle politics* is almost exclusively used as a critique of politicians on the right. (Indeed, this is implied by the last example sentence given above.) Typically, *dog whistles* hint at a view which is considered more extreme or polarising than that which is overtly stated.

In the United States, phrases used by politicians which have been called out as *dog whistles* include: *states' rights,* *food stamps,* *inner cities*, *Barack Hussein Obama* (where the whistle is the deliberate inclusion of the middle name), and, more recently, *bad hombres*.

*Dog whistles* are far more insidious than mere *platitudes* and are not unrelated to *doublespeak,* an answer previously given.

Answer (score 0):

Is [***xyloglossia/-lalia***](https://books.google.fr/books?id=fw8JpTCQnb4C&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=%22xylolalia%22&source=bl&ots=RMVsyChYnt&sig=40t3iR2CN1H9s8MlrrrlqFASnIs&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiizezG6O_dAhVyx4UKHUjFBVMQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22xylolalia%22&f=false) (lit. wooden language) the term you're after?

> Wooden language is language that uses vague, ambiguous, abstract or pompous words in order to divert attention from the salient issues. The  French scholar Françoise Thom identified four characteristics of wooden language: abstraction and the avoidance of the concrete, tautologies, bad metaphors, and Manichaeism that divides the world into good and evil. It originally referred to wording imposed by the Soviet Union. The phrase is a literal translation of the French expression *langue de bois*. The French phrase became widely used during the 1970s and 1980s, arriving in the language from Russian via Polish.
>
> The fictional language of Newspeak in George Orwell’s novel Nineteen 1984 often mirrors and satirizes wooden language.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wooden_language)

Answer (score -2):

Political doublespeak usually serves the purpose of obscuring the intention by naming the subject with an undeniably useful term. They serve the purpose of making a cause or idea sound new and legitimate when it is an old tired idea. I describe two terms and how they are used to misguide.

One term is *Income Inequality*. One will find it the world over especially in cities where low wage services are used by people making high and low wages. The goal in using the term is to complain about the reality, and plan to solve it most often by removing wealth from the wealthy.

My favorite is *Social Justice*. One cannot argue against justice but this attempts to address injustice that is not defined as such, yet, by normal legal description, only popular and emotional ones. Importantly, one could ask what justice is there outside of a society? None. As for ordinary justice, if it is injustice then the law should be enforced.

Comment: +1 for skewering 'social justice.' On the specific question, a lot turns on the intention of the user of the catchwords. If the user is just muddle-headed, then platitude comes close:"A remark or statement, especially one with a moral content, that has been used too often to be interesting or thoughtful."(Oxford online dictionaries), but maybe you are referring to the statement that is on its way to becoming a platitude. If the intention is to mislead or to deceive, then doublespeak comes close.

Comment: I'm doubtful that I have correct interpretation of what you were trying to say as I had some difficulty deciphering your comment. However I believe your second example of social justice was in and of itself an example of what I'm looking for. You used the term "Justice" in reference to conformity with our current legislature/precedence. However "Justice" is an idea that both evolves in accord with social mores and varies person-to-person. Your argument appeals to our intrinsic attraction towards "justice" without addressing that your and mine and society's may contradict. - I was too slow 8.8

Comment: This post appears to be a comment on the "doublespeak" answer already given. This is actually a question and answer page, not a discussion thread. Each answer that you post in an answer box is expected to stand alone as an expert answer to the question at the top. Answer posts that are not attempts to answer the question may be removed. See: “[Why and how are some answers deleted? - Help Center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)”.

Comment: If I misunderstood and you intended the emphasized words "income inequality" and "social justices" to be your answer, then I should point out that the question is what to call this category of terms as a whole. Examples do not answer the question.

Comment: Incidentally, you have described injustice as that which is unlawful, but that is too narrow. Laws and other social institutions can be unjust. The idea of *social justice* is to recognize and change social structures which, for example, create unfair barriers to opportunity for certain populations, or withhold social protection and basic services from powerless individuals. If you'd like to continue to discuss these ideas using this question as a springboard, join our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).